# dynamically change marquee text without changing position of marquee

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, dynamic, marquee

I am currently working on stock based web application and i want to display price of different stocks in marquee. Due to frequent change of stock prices i had to update text of marquee dynamically. Its easy to change text, but after updation marquee starts from initial position and thats the problem. Is there any way to change text without changing its current position???

I'm currently using update panel and timer to change its text.

```
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="True" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer> 
        <marquee id="marque" style="width: 700px" direction="right" runat="server"></marquee>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

and changing text using back end .cs file
marque.InnerText = dynamic_data;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you change the text in the code-behind file. That means a post-back is needed to change the text. A post-back is nothing else than a full reload of the page and for sure it resets your marquee.

Change the text on client side per javascript. If you need to bring the text out of the back-end, use a page method and connect from client-side to it.

Comment: Thanks but i had try to change text using simple javascript but whenever text changes it automatically starts from the beginning.

Comment: what exactly have you done to implement the text change per javascript? you used an asp button or something like that? Because then you must intercept the post-back also by returning false from javascript or the asp-control initiates again a postback.

Comment: I have tried it using this way....                            <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = "a";
        function loadMarquee() {
             i += "a";
            document.getElementById("marque").innerHtml = "Hello World";
            setInterval(loadMarquee(),100);
        }
        loadMarquee();
    </script>                                                            but it didnt work

Comment: the question is how you trigger the function.

Comment: using seInterval i had set trigger time for this function 100 miliseconds

Comment: the set interval is inside your loadMarquee function that means whenever the function gets called you set a new interval. within a few seconds you have then set hundreds of intervals

Comment: thanks for improvement in method but it isn't the problem,we can put it outside function so it will executes once. but innerHtml doesn't work here

Comment: is there any change you have a live example to see the full thing?

Comment: you have that somewhere online where I can see it live?

Comment: I think i should load dynamic data in division tag and try to sort out problem...thanks for your support.

Comment: finally sortout problem with some variables and logic....initializeStocks();
        data.InnerHtml = "";
        for (int i = marqueePos; i <= marqueePos + marqueeSize; i++)
        {
            data.InnerHtml += "&nbsp;"+stocks[i%stocks.Length]+" : "+loadStockPrize(stocks[i%stocks.Length])+"&nbsp;";
        }
        marqueePos++;
        marqueePos = marqueePos % stocks.Length;